# Получить такой объект List, у которого значение одного из свойств минимальная

Tags: java, list, коллекции, сравнение

Есть такой класс:

```
public class Banner {
    private Map<String,Integer> viewedUsers;
    // Прочие переменные
    // Setters & Getters
}
```

Есть такой список

```
List<Banner> bannerList;
```

Ключом в `Map<String, Integer>` является ID-пользователя, а значением кол-во просмотров. Ключ известен. Как получить элемент List, для которого значение viewedUsers.get(key) минимальная относительно других элементов. Проще говоря, как получить баннер, которую просмотрели как можно меньшее кол-во раз?

Comment: Вам нужен баннер с наименьшим числом просмотра данным пользователем или всеми пользователями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно для каждого пользователя отдельно:

```
Collections.min(
  bannerList, 
  Comparator.comparingInt(banner -> banner.viewedUsers.get(userId))
);
```

Если нужно для всех пользователей:

```
ToIntFunction<Banner> viewsCounter = banner -> banner.viewedUsers.values().stream()
   .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
   .sum();
Collections.min(
  bannerList, 
  Comparator.comparingInt(viewsCounter)
);
```

Но нужно с этим осторожно. Java8 для людей слабо знакомых с ней выглядит неразборчивым ужасом. Тут больше посыл в использовании Comparator.comparingIint и отсутствие сортировки, которая вообще ни к чему для данной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть у класса `Banner` есть некоторый метод, который возвращает число просмотров

```
public class Banner {
    private Map<String,Integer> viewedUsers;
    public int getTotalViews() {...}
}
```

Тогда поиск минимального элемента в списке можно осуществить при помощи статического метода `Collections.min()`

```
Collections.min(
  bannerList,
  (item1, item2) -> Integer.compare(item1.getTotalViews(), item2.getTotalViews())
);
```

Comment: Создавать методы в классах моделях который выполняют какую либо бизнес логику не есть хорошо.

Comment: @GVArt Согласен. Инкапсуляцию придумали слабаки

Answer (score -1):

Создайте `Comparator`

```
class BannerComparator implements Comparator<Banner> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Banner b1, Banner b2) {
        int sumOne = b1.getViewedUsers().values().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
        int sumTwo = b2.getViewedUsers().values().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();

        return Integer.compare(sumOne, sumTwo);
    }
}
```

Дальше отсортируйте ваш список и возьмите первый элемент:

```
List<Banner> bannerList = ...
bannerList.sort(new BannerComparator());
Banner minViewsBanner = bannerList.get(0);
```

Comment: Зачем его сортировать? Чтобы процессор не охлаждался?